# Access violation 0xc0000005 on exit with JNI Cygwin code on Windows XP

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, cygwin, gcc4

I'm stumped on this. I have JNI code that works on Ubuntu 11 and MacOSX but cause problems with Windows.

JRE version: 6.0_31-b05
OS: Windows XP with gcc 4. Modified jni_md.h to avoid the _int64 compile error: http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2006-May/085047.html

Code is built and run using Maven. The error happens when running our unit test which runs perfectly on Ubuntu 11 and MacOSX.

A few observations.

1) There was one function that returns String. That would cause the unit test to freeze. Here's the signature.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_ctrlworks_puppet_driver_DefaultDriver_Get_1FW_1Version(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
```

2) Taking out the function from being invoked and modifying unit test accordingly causes the unit test to run through with no errors but causes the access violation at exit.

Stack trace:

```
Current thread (0x02c1ac00):  VMThread [stack: 0x02d00000,0x02d50000] [id=3360]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x02d4de30

Registers:
EAX=0x02d4ce64, EBX=0x001b2b28, ECX=0x00000001, EDX=0x00000001
ESP=0x02d4fc14, EBP=0x02d4fc5c, ESI=0x02d4fc70, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x6102879e, EFLAGS=0x00010212

EAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x02d00000,0x02d50000],  sp=0x02d4fc14,  free space=319k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [cygwin1.dll+0x2879e]  dll_noncygwin_dllcrt0+0x1e
C  [ntdll.dll+0x118a]  LdrInitializeThunk+0x24
C  [ntdll.dll+0x23aba]  RtlDestroyEnvironment+0x178
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1ca96]  IsValidLocale+0x8eb
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1cb0e]  ExitProcess+0x14
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x8d04]  exit+0x0
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x8d11]  exit+0xd
V  [jvm.dll+0x11d88d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11cb9e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11cec2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11d2d2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x140ffc]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb713]  GetModuleFileNameA+0x1b4

VM_Operation (0x009efb80): Exit, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x003b7000
```

Your help most appreciated.
I'm a complete Windows novice and that doesn't help.
I tried to look into Visual C++ 2010 but got a lot of compile errors so decided I'm better off with Cygwin. We also have quite a bit of scripting logic in BASH, so we need the Cygwin environment anyway.

Comment: don't modify jni_md.h.  define CPP macros to fix the error (e.g. #define __int64 long long).

Comment: You'll need to provide more details w/r/t what your C code is actually doing, or at least an overview of the operations you're invoking.

Comment: Have you considered avoiding the per-platform JNI layers and using JNA (http://github.com/twall/jna) instead?  It'd reduce the level of platform-specific coding you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did #define __int64 to long long.

Comment: The code is meant to drive a microcontroller using the USB serial port via POSIX termios. That part of the code may also need some changes but I'd at least want to make sure the JNI portion is working. I'm not familiar with JNA so never considered that. If it comes down to that, I'll have to consider it or perhaps a Java USB interface. We are under tight time constraints and would not want to create any new code if necessary.

Comment: Compile and link options: `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias` `-L /lib/mingw -W,--kill-at -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared`

Comment: If your API/library exports a standard C API then JNA allows you to write a simple Java interface and avoid any native code whatsoever.

Comment: I tried JNA and got into the same cygwin1.dll runtime error as with JNI. Instead of debugging this problem, I've decided to just move to Visual C++. In that sense, the problem is with cygwin1.dll. Was able to get around the problem by not using cygwin1.dll in the runtime. To do that though, we had to rewrite some of our existing code that has dependency on termios.h

Answer (score 2):

You most definitely *don't* want to build a JNI library against cygwin.dll.  There isn't anything in cygwin that you would want in your final JNI library.

Either build with MSVC, mingw, or use the -mno-cygwin flag using cygwin gcc.